# My External Hard Drive will not mount using GUI

Tags: mount, 22.04, hard-drive, exfat

I recently ran into an issue where my external hard drive can only be mounted using the command line arguments such as `sudo mount -t exfat /dev/sdb1 /mnt/External`. When I try to mount the drive using the GUI in Ubuntu's file manager I get the error message below. [image]
Any help is appreciated!

P.S. The hard drive is a 500GB SSD formatted in exfat.I am using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

After spending some time looking for the issue I determined that that the
`/etc/fstab` file had a duplicate entry in it that was using the UUID of the disk. I fixed it by removing the entry and remounting the disk. This was caused by me messing with the mount points in the disk utility and not unmounting the drive beforehand. I made the mistake of changing the option labeled "identify as" to Label instead of UUID.

- Labels can change the UUID can't!